# Deep Learning CNN ValueError: as_list() is not defined on an unknown TensorShape

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I've load the dataset preprocessed the image data using this code:

```
data = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory('/content/drive/MyDrive/PengantarSainsData/Capstone2/dataset_revisi')
data_iterator = data.as_numpy_iterator()
batch = data_iterator.next()
def preprocess(x, y):
    x_normalized = x / 255
    y_one_hot = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y, num_classes=5)
    return x_normalized, y_one_hot
data = data.map(lambda x, y: tf.py_function(func=preprocess, inp=[x, y], Tout=[tf.float32, tf.float32]))
scaled_iterator = data.as_numpy_iterator()
batch = scaled_iterator.next()
```

Then partitioned it into training, validation, and testing data using this code:

```
train_size = int(len(data) * .7)
val_size = int(len(data) * .2)
test_size = int(len(data) * .1)
train = data.take(train_size)
val = data.skip(train_size).take(val_size)
test = data.skip(train_size + val_size).take(test_size)
```

also created the model architecture, this way:

```
model.add(Conv2D(16, (3, 3), 1, activation = 'relu', input_shape = (256, 256, 3)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D())

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), 1, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D())

model.add(Conv2D(16, (3, 3), 1, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D())

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation = 'relu')) # 256 number of units used in dense layer
model.add(Dense(5, activation = 'softmax')) # sigmoid represents 0 and 1 output

model.compile('adam', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

model.summary()
```

then when I want to do the training process:

```
logdir = 'logs'
tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir = logdir)
hist = model.fit(train, epochs = 16, validation_data = val, callbacks = [tensorboard_callback])
```

it keeps throwing errors as attached to the picture. What should i do? Been struggling with this for 2 days
[image]

i've tried a different model, and using this code below to defining its architecture more specifically
`model.build(input_shape=(None, 256, 256, 3))`
but it still didn't work

Answer (score 1):

I think that you did some unnecessary steps with `as_numpy_iterator`. Your `image_dataset_from_directory` is a `tf.data.Dataset` which you can manipulate directly without turning it into a NumPy iterator. You will simply need to use `tf.one_hot` instead of `tf.keras.utils.to_categorical`.

Here's a full example that works, using a local version of MNIST (you'll have to change the path and number of categories:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *

data = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(r'path\to\mnist\test')


def preprocess(x, y):
    x_normalized = x / 255
    y_one_hot = tf.one_hot(tf.cast(y, tf.int32), depth=10)
    return x_normalized, y_one_hot


data = data.map(preprocess)

train_size = int(len(data) * .7)
val_size = int(len(data) * .2)
test_size = int(len(data) * .1)
train = data.take(train_size)
val = data.skip(train_size).take(val_size)
test = data.skip(train_size + val_size).take(test_size)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(16, (3, 3), 1, activation='relu', input_shape=(256, 256, 3)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D())

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), 1, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D())

model.add(Conv2D(16, (3, 3), 1, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D())

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))   
model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax')) 

model.compile('adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()

logdir = 'logs'
tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=logdir)
hist = model.fit(train, epochs=1, validation_data=val, callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])
```